Do random events increase the minimal description complexity of a worldview?
If we think of worldviews as sets of statements that describe reality, then a worldview with more statements is more complex than one with fewer statements. Given a set of statements, S, we could, in principle, simplify S by finding an axiomatization—a minimal set of foundational statements from which all other true statements in S can be derived through logical inference. Thus, given two theories or worldviews, S and S', we can apply this axiomatization approach to each and then compare them based on the number of statements in their axiomatization. Philosopher Graham Oppy is well-known for proposing worldview comparisons in this way.
Now, suppose a worldview allows for genuinely random events, such as those in quantum mechanics. In that case, it’s unclear how a set of axiomatic statements, S, containing descriptions of the Big Bang singularity and statements about physical laws, could logically derive the outcomes of future random events. For S to account for the results of random events, it would need to include explicit statements about each outcome, meaning the complexity of S would increase with every new random event.
Unless I’m missing something.
Do random events increase the minimal description complexity of a worldview?

Yes, they trivially do, since they by definition would be not determined. Note, however, that truly random events only occur depending on certain interpretations of QM. Secondly, events are relative to description and certain macro scale events may still be inevitable. For example, initial conditions + physical laws may be enough to lead to the formation of the earth with probability 1, even if events like a certain Radon atom decaying yesterday occur with probability 0.1.

The "worldview" is not a laundry list of statements describing every event in the world, past, present and future, it is a big picture account of how the world works, its laws and patterns, a "theory of everything". There is no need for it to "derive" every statement that is, was or will be true, and it makes no difference whether events they are about are random or not. What matters is how complex the rules that govern those events are. A worldview that there are no rules, even statistical ones, and everything is 'random' (lawless) will be the simplest of all.

@Conifold How is that a simple worldview? If there are no rules, then there is nothing to explain anything occurring in the world. Every event in the world becomes truly random, and thus every event occurs through no explanation. This is exactly why processes such as Solomonoff induction were created, to remove the ambiguities behind what consitutes as an explanation. If every event is truly random, and we take that to be our data, there is no algorithm that can compress that data. That is the most complex thing possible.

This question lacks any kind of actual motivation or precision and seems to be based on several gross caricatures of what a "wordview" might be, what axiomatization is (what the purpose is, how it's done, when it can be done and when not), what randomness is, how complexity is measured - So I vote to close the question.

@Syed The question is about complexity of a worldview, not complexity of events in the world. A no explanation worldview is simple, being simple does not make it useful or accurate.

@Conifold I'm saying that a no explanation worldview is both useless and complex. A no explanation worldview would simply contain all the data without compression, which is quite literally as complex as you can get from an elegance point of view. It's a bit like saying that an unzipped data file is simple but a zipped file is complex: that's not how it works. The whole point of zipping files is to find a way to compress data through a simpler pattern

@mudskipper Would this serve as motivation? I can't find the exact moment when Oppy talks about axiomatizations, but here Oppy is talking about theories at least: https://youtu.be/m-80lQOlNOs?t=1295

@user80226 - No, not for me, unless you tell more about it in the question itself.

@Syed The data about events is irrelevant to the complexity of the worldview, apparently you are missing the difference. A no explanation worldview contains no data at all.

@Conifold What you're talking about is the equivalent of having no theory to explain the data at hand. Having no theory isn't a worldview. It's the lack of one, so talking about the simplicity or complexity of it is moot.


Do random events increase the minimal description complexity of a worldview?

Yes, they can. An interaction between random events can lead to emergent behavior; a new and unforseen consequence of the randomness that adds to the overall worldview complexity.
More information that is philosophy specific: https://iep.utm.edu/emergence/
Typically, however, random events add to the background noise and increase the uncertainty of the outcome. So while the outcome is more complex (less predictable) the mechanism generating the output does not increase in complexity.
An example is ballistics:
A gun or cannon is constructed and has a fixed complexity. Now the gun is tested for accuracy.
The uncertainty in accuracy is much less in a controlled environment (no wind). The addition of random gusts of wind add to the uncertainty of the results but don't add any complexity to the gun or cannon.

The question isn’t about the complexity of a mechanism. It’s about the complexity of a worldview: two different things. If everything is truly random in a world, then that implies everything is unexplained. In order to generate that world, one would have to hard code all the data. This is as complex of a world as one can get.

Maybe the queston is not entirely coherent. I'll try to explain what I mean.
Given the requirements that:

A worldview is a set of statements that describes reality.
A worldview allows for quantum indeterminancy.

Your question is: Do random events increase the minimal description complexity of a worldview?
Since a worldview allows for quantum indeterminancy, it must contain statements that describe probability distributions. The number of statements is therefore the same regardless whether there exist random events or not.
If there are no random events we still have to allow for them as per the second requirement. The number of statements remains the same and thus the minimal description complexity remains the same.
If your question is: Do random events increase the minimal description complexity of a worldview that accounts for quantum indeterminancy as compared to a worldview that does not account for quantum indeterminancy, then you run into the problem that the latter no longer describes reality and, therefore, is not a worldview.

Randomness only increases complexity if you're trying to generate the universe from scratch and you're trying to bring about a particular result. Random events would continually deflect your desired trajectory through spacetime.
But in fact, complexity provides a larger field of possibilities from which the universe evolves.
Some of those possibilities yield, "I won the lottery!" Others yield, "Ooo, snake eyes! I'm sorry sir. Next rollah..."

